# ActionLink that acts like a text

Tags: c#, css, actionlink

I have an `@Html.ActionLink` in a webpage.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Hello ", "Index", "Manage", routeValues: new { Area = "" }, htmlAttributes: new { title = "Manage", @class = "user-btn clientName"})
```

looks like this:
[image]

The `clientName` contains the name of the user. I have an ajax call that sets the `clientName`

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: url,
            data: { userId: currentUserId },
            success: function (data) {
                $(".clientName").text($(".clientName").text() + data + "!");
            },
            failure: function (data) {
            }
        });
```

Now I need only a text instead of the ActionLink. I don't know how to use the `TextAreaFor` in this case. 
I have tried with a javascript to disable the link, it is disabled, but it is still a link.
Can you please help me with a `css` for ActionLink to be like a text, or with a solution to write that `clientName` in a text. Thanks

Comment: If the link is the text "Hello Bert..." then it already looks like text, what is it about it that you don't like? Presumably, you still require the user to click it?

Comment: No, I don't need to click it. So, I need to look like just a text, without that hand when I go over it

Comment: How are you triggering your ajax code? You can alter the hand using the `cursor` CSS property. If you want just text then just use a plain HTML element, such as a span.

Comment: Use html label instead of actionlink

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wants behave that test as link, and only wants to remove the under line and hand symbol you can use the following CSS.

```
text-decoration:none; 
cursor:text
```

or If you don't want the link behavior it self, you can directly use 
@Html.Label.

Answer (score 2):

You could replace the link with this:

```
$(".clientName").replaceWith("<span>"+$(".clientName").text() + data + "!</span>");
```

It will replace your `<a>` element with `<span>` which is not a clickable and it's a text.

Example:

```js
$(function(){
  $('.clientName').on('click', function(){
  
    $('.clientName').replaceWith( '<span>' + $('.clientName').text() + ' MORE TEXT!</span>' );
  
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<a href="#somelink" class="clientName">Click me</a>
```